# Can Docker image postgres:11.7-alpine talk to two servers at the same time?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am experiencing a connection error when trying to connect to my postgres instance which is a postgres:11.7-alpine image inside a container.

**my understanding:**

1. I have a codebase.
2. I have a container with a postgres:11.7-alpine image running inside it on port 5432:5432
3. I have a container with an image built from the codebase at point 1 above running on port 8000:8000.

Inside the containers everything is running fine (meaning no errors and postgress is connected to point 3. I used `docker-compose up --build`

When I try to start up my codebase (point 1) it gets a connection error. I suspect it is trying to connect to postgres (point 2) but the postgres inside the container is already connected to my replica codebase (point 3)

**How to replicate**

`docker-compose up --build`

*result everything runs fine*

then I startup my codebase (point 1) and it gets a connection error.

**Expect behaviour**

`docker-compose up --build`
*result everything runs fine*
then I startup my codebase (point 1) and is also able to connect to the postgres instance within the docker container.

```
version: '3.6'
services:

  # App Backend PostgreSQL
  postgres:
    container_name: sportsAppApiDb
    image: postgres:11.7-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_URL: postgres://admin:password@localhost:5432/sportsappapi
      POSTGRES_DB: sportsappapi
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  # App Backend
  sports-app-api:
    container_name: sportsAppApi
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/sports-app-api
    command: sbt run
    working_dir: /usr/src/sports-app-api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_URI: postgres://admin:password@postgres:5432/sportsappapi
```

Comment: I'm guessing in the first case you're trying to call this setup from outside of Docker.  How are you configuring the database connection there?  What is the actual error you're getting?  (PostgreSQL in Docker doesn't have the sort of constraint you describe where it can only accept connections from one place at a time.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you want to connect to the `postgres` from a docker container as well as from an app that is being run from the IDE. Since you are binding the postgres port from container to host machine, to connect another app, you can use the `5432` port of the host machine.

Connection string for codebase in the IDE would be

`postgres://admin:password@0.0.0.0:5432/sportsappapi`

But this will only work if `docker-compose up --build` is up and running.

Comment: `postgres` is the name of the Compose service block and this will also be usable as a host name, assuming the client is running in Docker in the same Compose setup.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes this further.  (I tend to recommend deleting `container_name:` since there's an alternate usable network name, and Compose can pick a unique container name on its own.)

Comment: @fullStackRyan I didn't fully understand your question earlier. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @MjZac Thanks for taking time to answer.

I changed my docker-compose file to this 

```
  # App Backend
  sports-app-api:
    container_name: sportsAppApi
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/sports-app-api
    command: sbt run
    working_dir: /usr/src/sports-app-api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_URI: postgres://admin:password@0.0.0.0:5432/sportsappapi
      depends_on: sportsAppApiDb
```
still not working.